# How to transfer cells with values stored as text using VBA, without Excel converting to numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that collates a set of data. I use a macro to transfer the rounded data to a file for the client. The collated data stores all values as text, so that trailing zeros are not lost.
e.g. "2.10" is correct, not "2.1".

The data is the return from a UDF that returns a string i.e. the data is a string but the cell containing it might not be formatted as text, just General format.

My macro attempts to set the `.Value2` fields in the destination (client) workbook, but reading from the .Text field of the source data.

e.g.

```
<example destination cell>.Value2 = <example source cell>.Text
```

Excel seems to be truncating trailing zeros in the destination file.

How can I end up with strings in the destination file?

Comment: Maybe  this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418589/vba-convert-a-few-numeric-cells-as-text) can help.

Comment: `<example destination cell>.Value2 = "'" & <example source cell>.Text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply text formatting first:

```
With DestinationCell
   .NumberFormat = "@"
   .Value2 = SourceCell.Text
End With
```

or prepend a `'`:

```
DestinationCell.Value2 = "'" & SourceCell.Text
```